# First connection to userEndpoint takes long time in Android with appEngine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In my android app, after sometime (hour or so.. not something determined) the connection and response to `Google-AppEngine` takes very long, something like 10 seconds or more.
After the first connection all other `enpoint` requests are done pretty quickly and this is why I believe this is SW issue and not internet connection issue.
Should I establish a 'dummy' connection as the app is loaded ?
Here is a sample code of an `AsyncTask` which tried to get `User entity` from `AppEngine endpoint` :

```
private class getUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    long mTaskUserId = Constants.USER_ID_NO_ID_INFDICATOR;
    String mIdInPlatform = Constants.USER_ID_NO_ID_INFDICATOR.toString();
    Long mServerScore;
    Context mContext;
    String mUserName;

    getUser(String idInPlatform, String userName, Context c) {
        mIdInPlatform = idInPlatform;
        mUserName = userName;
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Userendpoint.Builder builder = new Userendpoint.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
        builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);
        Userendpoint endpoint = builder.build();

        try {
            User user = endpoint.getUser().execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting user details from server ", e);
            return false;
        }
        this.mUserName = user.getUserName();
        this.mServerScore = user.getScore();
        this.mTaskUserId = user.getId();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            setUserFacebookIdInPreferences(mIdInPlatform, mContext);
            setUserIdInPreferences(this.mTaskUserId, mContext);
            setScoreInPreferences(this.mServerScore, mContext);
            setUserNameInPreferences(this.mUserName, mContext);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.string_login_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Restart login activity.
        moveToLoginActivity(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application in Google App Engine uses two types of server instances: Dynamic instances and Resident instances. The difference is that dynamic instances are created in demand to serve traffic requests. Resident instances are always on.

When traffic stops, all your dynamic instances will shut down to save resources (and help you save money). The first time a request hits the server, a new dynamic instance will spin off to serve that request. The process of starting a new instance might take some time.

This is very likely what you are seeing in your application. To avoid that initial latency you can do two different things:

1) Optimize the time it takes for your code to load up.
2) Set up a Resident instance.

You can find more information on the Google documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Introduction_to_Instances

Comment: So if many users will use the app, it is less likely the server will shutdown the instance ?  What about dummy connection on app load to initiate instance ? I believe the load time of the code is pretty much minimal since there isn't that much there.

Comment: That is correct. As more users send more traffic to your app, more dynamic instances will tend to stay running. Dummy traffic (fake) explicitly violates App Engine terms of service. A lot of people trick the system by creating a cron job that every sec pings the servers to keep instances alive, but this is not recommended. If you really need this, go with a Resident instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can warm-up your instances so that they're live before any query hits them - saving you this 10s delay. See documentation at:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Warmup_Requests